# Cannot import name 'input_function' from 'chatterbot.utils'

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot, chatterbot

I'm trying to implement feedback for bot replies created with chatterbot

https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/935#issuecomment-324230394
But it returns me 2 errors

The first:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'input_function' from 'chatterbot.utils' (/Users/xxx/Documents/.../utils.py)
```

The second one when I set the `DEFAULT_SESSION_ID = bot.default_session.id`:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'default_session' for class 'ChatBot'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous one is no longer used.
This and the new one.
It is used:

```
from chatterbot.conversation import Statement
```

With the appropriate changes to the code present in the example

https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/4ff8af28567ed446ae796d37c246bb6a14032fe7/examples/learning_feedback_example.py